# Can a proposition be false and its negation be false in Intuitionistic logic?

Tags: logic, computability, convention, intuitionistic-logic

The principle of non-contradiction say that p and $\neg$ p can not be both true.

1. If you consider the law of excluded middle as relevant, then either
   p or $\neg$ p is true, and thus the other is false by the principle
   of non-contradiction.
2. But if you consider the excluded middle as not relevant, just like
   intuitionistic logic, what would avoid some p and $\neg$ p to be
   both false ?

Actually, if true is the same than provable, then such a proposition is just a Gödel one : p is not provable and neither $\neg$ p is.

I think this is a very good interpretation and a big demystification of Gödel theorem : it is not about some true that we can not reach, it is about some absurdity that is still an absurdity when you negate it.

Comment: It is not possible, if by "$p$ is false" you mean "$\lnot p$ is provable". Indeed, then "$p$ and $\lnot p$ are both false" translate to "$\lnot p$ and $\lnot \lnot p$ are both provable", which is a contradiction. But "$p$ is false" is different from "$p$ is not provable".

Comment: No; the derivation of $\bot$ from $A \to \bot$ and $(A \to \bot) \to \bot$ is intuitionistically valid.

Comment: About the purported "big demystification of Gödel theorem" we have to note that G's Th is sound from an intuitionistic point of view... but it is "obvious". It is a cornerstone of Brouwer's view that Hilbert's assumption that every mathematical problem is decidable was not tenable.

Comment: I want to define a recursive logic where false is no longer define as  $\vDash \neg p$ but as $\nvDash p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement "$p$ and $\neg p$ are both false" is formally expressed as
$$\neg p \land \neg \neg p,$$
which is false by the law of non-contradiction, which states that for any $q$ the proposition $q \land \neg q$ is false (take $q = \neg p$).

More importantly, these consideration do *not* "demistyfy Gödel", as they refer to proposition with free propositional variables in them. Gödel constructed a **sentence**, i.e., a logical formula without free parameters, which is neither provable nor falsifiable (in a given formal system).

To put it another way, it is very easy to find a formula which is neither provable nor falsifiable, if we allow free variables, for example
$$x < 42$$
where $x$ ranges over the natural numbers (say, in Peano arithmetic) is not provable, but neither is
$$\neg (x < 42).$$

Comment: Sorry for "jumping into your post... There is [a question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4520337/in-logic-what-determines-if-a-proposition-is-negative-or-affirmative-positive) related to your [2010 post on negation and contradiction](http://math.andrej.com/2010/03/29/proof-of-negation-and-proof-by-contradiction/): we need your help :-)